# Proving Irreducibility of $X^{2p}+pX^n-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, solution-verification, irreducible-polynomials

The following is an exercise in Victor V. Prasolov's **Polynomials** (Second edition, Page no. $74$, exercise $2.10$)

**Problem:** Let $p>3$ be a prime and $n<2p$ a natural number. Prove that $$P(X)=X^{2p}+pX^n-1$$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

**My approach:** Let, if possible, assume that $P=fg$ for $2$ polynomials $f,g\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ with $\deg(f),\deg(g)\geq1$. For a polynomial $q\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ let $\overline{q}$ denote its reduction modulo $p$. Then $$\overline{P}=X^{2p}-1=(X^p+1)(X^p-1)=(X+1)^p(X-1)^p$$ Therefore $\overline{f}\overline{g}=(X-1)^p(X+1)^p$.

**Edit:** According to @WhatsUp's solution we must have $\overline{f}=X^p+1,\overline{g}=X^p-1$(or vice-versa).

**Update:** Then we have $f(X)=X^p+1+pF(X)$ and $g(X)=X^p-1+pG(X)$ for some $F,G\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Since $\deg(f)+\deg(g)=\deg(P)=2p$ and $P$ is monic and $X^n$ has coefficient $p$ and all other coefficients are $0$ we must have $\deg(F),\deg(G)\leq p-1$. If $F,G$ were both non-zero then equating $P$ and $fg$ we have $$(G(X)-F(X))+X^p(G(X)+F(X))+pG(X)F(X)=X^n$$ Therefore, since $p>3$ is an odd prime, evaluating at $X=1$ we get $$G(1)(2+pF(1))=1$$ This means $$pF(1)=\pm1-2$$ equivalently, $pF(1)=-3$ or $pF(1)=-1$. The latter is not possible. For the former case we must have $p=3$ but $p>3$ is given.

A contradiction in all cases since $G(1),f(1)\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $p>3$ is an odd prime!

Then one of $F,G$ must be the $0$ polynomial. Let $F\equiv0$. Let $G$ be a non-zero polynomial. Then we have $$X^{2p}+pX^n-1=(X^p+1)(X^p-1+pG(X))=X^{2p}-1+pX^pG(X)+pG(X)$$ That means $$pX^pG(X)-pG(X)=pX^n\implies X^pG(X)-G(X)=X^p\implies G(X)(X^p-1)=X^n$$ which implies $0=G(1)(1^p-1)=1^n=1$, a contradiction! Therefore such $F,G$ can't exist. Again $(X^p+1)(X^p-1)\neq P(X)$. Then $P$ can't be factorized over $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ or equivalently $P$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

<s>Is this argument correct? Can someone tell me if this proof is correct or wrong?</s>

Comment: The implication $\gcd(f, g) = 1 \implies \gcd(\overline f, \overline g) = 1$ is incorrect. Consider $f = X$, $g = X + p$.

Comment: @WhatsUp But if $\gcd(f,g)=1$ then $\exists$ $u,v$ such that $uf+vg=1$. Reducing mod $p$ we get $\bar{u}\bar{f}+\bar{v}\bar{g}=1$. Or $\gcd(\bar{f},\bar{g})=1$.

Comment: No, this only works for polynomials over **fields**. In $\Bbb Z[X]$ there is no euclidean division that creates Bezout's identity. $\Bbb Z[X]$ is just a unique factorization domain, not a principal ideal domain.

Comment: @WhatsUp then how can I proceed for the proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To justify your argument, I will show that we must have $\overline f = X^p + 1$, $\overline g = X^p - 1$ or vice-versa.

Suppose that this is not the case. Then either $X + 1$ or $X - 1$ would divide both $\overline f$ and $\overline g$.

Let's say $X - 1$ divides both of them (the other case being similar).

This means that $p\mid f(1)$ and $p\mid g(1)$, hence $p^2 \mid f(1)g(1) = P(1)$.

But we have $P(1) = p$, a contradiction.

---

To continue the argument, let $F, G$ be as in your post. Thus we have $$X^{2p} + pX^n - 1 = (X^p + 1 + pF)(X^p - 1 + pG).$$ This leads to $$(X^p - 1)F + (X^p + 1)G + pFG = X^n.$$

Now plug in $X = 1$, we get $(2 + pF(1))G(1) = 1$, which means $2 + pF(1)$ must be $1$ or $-1$.

Hence $pF(1)$ must be $-1$ or $-3$. This is only possible for $p = 3$, which we check manually.

Comment: Thanks! Then rest of my argument proving the irreducibility is correct, right?

Comment: I'm not sure how you conclude in the case that $F, G$ are both non-zero. Maybe it should be expanded a bit there?

Comment: If $F, G$ are both non-zero then $P(X)$ contains the term $p^2F(X)G(X)$ and hence at least one term with coefficient which is a multiple of $p^2$. But $P(X)$ contains no term with a coefficient which is a multiple of $p^2$.

Comment: But there are other terms, such as $pX^pF(X)$, $pX^pG(X)$, $pF(X)$ and $pG(X)$. It is *a priori* possible that their combination gives a term containing $p^2$. I think there should be an argument of degree or something like that which eliminates this possibility.

Comment: Yes, Let me think about that case. I must use another method for this case.

Comment: Now I think my argument is correct. Can you check once?

Comment: I added a continuation of the proof.

Comment: Yeah! that's the same I just did. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, great that you found it yourself! My page didn't refresh and I didn't see it before submitting the edit.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. Really Stack exchange has a lot of great teachers like you and also friends.

Comment: It was a real pleasure attempting and partially solving it.